# Qt Creator's intellisense grays out #ifdef _DEBUG blocks even though Debug build is selected

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, conditional-compilation

When I have in my code an `#ifdef` like this

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    printf("This is a debug build");
#endif
```

Qt Creator grays out the `printf` even though it is a debug build, and when I run it `"This is a debug build"` gets printed.

It seems that the intellisense isn't seeing the preprocessor defines that will be passed to the compiler via the command line (i.e. `-D_DEBUG`) instead of being defined in the header/source files.

Comment: You'll want to look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8298770/159834

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't have a config file in my project directory. Also how do I make it define _DEBUG for debug builds only, but not for release builds?

Comment: Just create it. I don't know how to do it conditionally on the build type, though.

Comment: It needs to change automatically between Debug and Release builds, otherwise it wouldn't be a useful workaround. I would need to edit the .config file each time I change the Build mode. This probably is a bug/oversight in Qt Creator. The intellisense should see the same preprocessor defines that the compiler will see.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following works just fine in my `*.pro` file:

```
CONFIG(debug, release|debug):DEFINES += _DEBUG
```

Switching the build type then also swaps the greyed-out area. I'm using Qt5, though.

Comment: Thanks for this little but very useful for me a Qt (Creator) newbie hint!